# Linear Layout Adjustment is Not able to set

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

[image]

How to add another button under the call button? 
What should I do so that it comes  down of call button? 
so suggest me that 
[image]

Comment: Share the xml layout which you have written

Comment: share your code

Comment: Justin accept the answer if its helpful to you

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Call"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OtherButton"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```